# CakePHP: inserting into a MySQL ARCHIVE engine table

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.4

I have a small ARCHIVE engine table that I want to submit logs into whenever someone does something. I am **not** giving a unique "id" to every row; instead my "id" column is the user's ID.

I use `this->model->save()` and the first insert is fine. The problem is Cake thinks I'm trying to UPDATE on the second time that someone does something, when really all I want is to create another record, with the same user's ID, with a different action or timestamp.

How do I force CakePHP to INSERT only, without using `query()`? And without having to make 5th column for "row ID"?

Comment: Please provide more information - are you using the `create()` -> `set()` -> `save()` method? If you are and it is still updating, I suggest you give the model a unique ID and ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

Always make sure to unset the primary key. For instance in the beforeValidate. This will trigger a save instead of an update.

[See the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-save-array-data-null-boolean-validate-true-array-fieldlist-array)

Comment: I'm close to just writing my own answer, but this steered me in the right direction. It turns out CakePHP assumes any "id" column is a primary key; in short, I seriously just changed the column's name from "id" to "uid" and now it works. Bizarre. I'm going to wait to see if someone can give some clarity on how this works, but if nothing, I'll accept your answer.